# Twilio: HTTP communication total time out triggered

Tags: timeout, twilio

Error - 11203 
HTTP communication total time out triggered

Twilio webhook is getting timeout. Below is the suggestion.

https://www.twilio.com/docs/api/errors/11203#error-11203

**All attempts to communicate with your web server were timed out. You set the total timeout using the tt parameter in the URL fragment identifier.**

*How to implement this timeout settings?*

Answer (score 1):

It looks like the blog post below will provide you more insight.

[Announcing Twilio’s HTTP Callbacks (webhooks) Connection Overrides for Voice](https://www.twilio.com/blog/announcing-twilios-http-callbacks-webhooks-connection-overrides-for-voice)